# checking response control just "connected" or not with wget

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I have just trying to write a script which just controls about the response contains "connected" or not

```
 #!/bin/bash
cat control.txt | while read link // control.txt contains http and https urls
do
if [[ $(wget --spider -S $link 2>&1 | grep "connected") =~~ *"connected"* ]];
then echo "OK"; 
else echo "FAIL";
fi
done
```

Output:

```
sh -x portcontrol.sh 
portcontrol.sh[2]: Syntax error at line 4 : `=~' is not expected.
```

Comment: And...  did it work?  If not, what's the error?  Please improve  your question so people can help you

Comment: not working when i try with sh -x responsecontrol.sh it says unexpected =~~ "connected"

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the whole error.  Preferably everything: the prompt running the script and the actual error message

Comment: its okay coud you please help right now ?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue exactly as it is, but one thing caught my attention.  This token: `=~~`.  I know bash has `=~`, but not with two tildes.  What do you mean by `=~~`?

Comment: As a side note, this looks weird, too: `*"connected"*`.  What do you mean by these stars?

Comment: I see at least four problems: 1) bash doesn't have a `=~~` operator; you may want `=~` for regular expression comparison, except 2) `*"connected"*` appears to be a glob (wildcard) expression instead of a regular expression, so you probably want `=` instead. 3)rd, running the script with `sh` overrides the shebang and may run the script with something other than bash. Finally, you should have double-quotes around `$link`. Oh, and `cat somefile | ...` is a classic useless use of `cat`; use `done < somefile` at the end instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to see if the connection request succeeded, and the `wget` output is of the form:

```
Connecting to <hostname>|<ip_addr>|:<port>... connected.
```

it should be sufficient to just do:

```
if [[ $(wget --spider -S $link 2>&1 | grep -c " connected\.") -gt 0 ]];
  then echo "OK"; 
  else echo "FAIL";
fi
```

Checking exit code works too, but it depends on what your requirements really are.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your script correctly, you're retrieving the page, but ignoring its contents, and all you want is to see whether `wget` shows the string 'connected'.

If that is so,  your code can be simplified as follows:

```
if wget --spider -S $link 2>&1 | grep "connected" > /dev/null
then 
    echo "OK"; 
else 
    echo "FAIL";
fi
```

You don't need to capture wget's output and run a regexp search on it; grep already returns 0 (success) or 1 (not found) when searching for the string you gave.

That return code can be used directly to control the `if`.

The output of grep is redirected to `/dev/null` as to not show up on the screen or script output.